TP-Link AC600 archer driver for Linux Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
I have tried multiple times to install this driver on my Ubuntu Virtual machine (on VirtualBox) and it seems to have failed.
I've followed these for example:
TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 24.04
TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Plus driver for Ubuntu 20.04
Some "shots":
https://i.ibb.co/ckKGKx0/Virtual-Box-Linux-Ubuntu-03-11-2024-12-26-27.png
https://i.ibb.co/LYT6chd/Virtual-Box-Linux-Ubuntu-03-11-2024-12-27-13.png
https://i.ibb.co/cXRTtcK/Virtual-Box-Linux-Ubuntu-03-11-2024-12-27-30.png
What am I doing wrong ?
Update: Solved by installing this : https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708
!
Thank you to everyone.

Your driver seems to work, are there wifi access points around?

I suspect your TP-LINK ARCHER AC600 [RTL8812AU] driver is not working for the new kernel.
As there is some confusion if it is RTL8812AU or RTL8821AU I will add both below. IT IS RESOLVED - IT SHOULD BE RTL8821AU
You could try the driver here. I think yours is on this. (8812au/8821au). However, it will involve working with sources and the ubuntu DKMs (Auto rebuild mechanism for drivers etc).
https://github.com/morrownr
Compatible Kernels
8812au
Kernels: 5.4 - 5.11 (Realtek)
Kernels: 5.12 - 6.11 (community support)

8821au
Kernels: 5.4 - 5.11 (Realtek)
Kernels: 5.12 - 6.10 (community support)

You can remove the current driver with the following command
sudo modprobe -r rtl8812au
sudo modprobe -r rtl8821au

sudo modprobe rtl8812au should re-install it
sudo modprobe rtl8821au should re-install it
DKMS
Use
dkms status

To identify the device driver (RTL8812AU/RTL8821AU) for each succesfully built kernel. Your original driver source could/will have an uninstall to uninstall it. If not then you could uninstall it as follows: -
Typical output of dkms status
rtl88XXau/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88XXau/X.XX.X.X, 6.8.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed

Typical removal from the dkms. If it is removed it should also stop the driver installing but you might have to reboot to achieve this. You need to use your details of the driver you have installed but here are are some examples. (Note: Only uninstall from non-active or broken driver kernels.)
dkms remove rtl88XXau/x.x.x.x --all
dkms remove rtl88XXau/x.x.x.x -k  6.8.0-45-generic -a x86_64


Installation
Open a gnome-terminal
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade #normal updates
sudo apt install -y build-essential dkms git iw #Tools needed
mkdir -p ~/src #make a directory to place the sources
cd ~/src #move to directory
Select your driver
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8812au-20210820.git
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git

cd ~/src/8812au-20210820 #Move into sources
cd ~/src/8821au-20210708 #Move into sources
sudo ./install-driver.sh #(Note to remove it run ./remove-driver.sh).
If you are running secure boot and you have not installed a MOK key the driver will not get signed so it will not run. The instructions on the site do give some advice regarding this. (In particular the section on manual installation.)
I think it is a good idea to reboot before you starting testing.
To check the driver is installed in the dkms (for auto build when the kernel gets updated) run the following
sudo dkms status

I hope this is of some help

Thanks for the comprehensive reply. Well, I am not sure what to do now... I've installed what you suggested, but it seems I didn't remove the other driver version... also, the first time when the script asked me whether to edit the driver config, I chose "Yes", then closed the terminal and the VM came to a "black screen"/Like the BSOD on Windows... so I uninstalled, reinstalled and now I have:
sudo dkms status
realtek-rtl88xxau, 5.6.4.2~20240509: added
rtl8812au, 5.13.6-23, 5.15.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
What to do now ? Load the driver manually ? The device is still not working..

This won't work as the device isn't rtl8812au, it is rtl8821au, the aircrack-ng driver should work with 8812au, 8814au, and 8821au

Just to mention, there are a LOT of networks where I am, and on Windows the device is working fine.
I'm afraid that I created a mess in my Ubuntu VM... can I create a new user profile to begin from 0 or something without new OS install ?
https://i.ibb.co/nB3cMsY/Virtual-Box-Linux-Ubuntu-03-11-2024-15-35-12.png
(it says "monitor because I tried to use with Fluxion ...) but in Managed it's the same.
Now the WiFi menu is visible again, but no networks detected...

Another info that maybe is important: The full model of my device is : "Archer T2U Plus (EU) Ver: 1.0", as written on the box. IDK if it makes any difference.

@Jeremy I did wonder if it should be rtl8821au instead of rtl8812au. I have a Edimax Technology Co., Ltd Edimax AC600 USB and that uses the former. However, there is so many links reporting the TP-link AC600 as using the rtl8812au. The site in this answer does have both so you can choose. If it is confirmed its the rtl8821au I will update the answer accordingly.

@FREEMAN The answer does describe how to remove previous drivers for the target device. You might need to get the name right though. lshw -c network will tell you the currently loaded driver. dkms status will tell you what is in the dkms and previous builds should have a script to remove them and if not then the answer suggests another way to do it. Don't forget if you are running 'secure boot' you must have a private MOK key to build the driver or it won't work.

I updated the answer to cater for both so you can pick the one you want.
