apt-get upgrade failing with errors due to linux-headers-generic on 24.04.1 LTS
I logged in to my 24.04.1 LTS system after a while, and decided to upgrade and update using the sudo apt-get commands. While apt-get update ran successfully, on running apt-get upgrade, I am getting the following errors:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode bpfcc-tools bpftrace ieee-data intel-microcode iucode-tool libbpfcc libclang-cpp18 libclang1-18 libjs-inherits libjs-regenerate libjs-sprintf-js libllvm18 libnode109 linux-modules-6.8.0-48-generic linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-48-generic
  linux-tools-6.8.0-48 linux-tools-6.8.0-48-generic node-acorn node-ajv node-ansi-regex node-ansi-styles node-argparse node-balanced-match node-brace-expansion node-busboy node-chalk node-cjs-module-lexer node-color-convert node-color-name
  node-concat-stream node-core-util-is node-debug node-deep-is node-doctrine node-escape-string-regexp node-eslint-scope node-eslint-utils node-eslint-visitor-keys node-espree node-esprima node-esquery node-esrecurse node-estraverse node-esutils
  node-fast-deep-equal node-fast-levenshtein node-file-entry-cache node-flat-cache node-flatted node-fs.realpath node-functional-red-black-tree node-glob node-glob-parent node-globals node-graceful-fs node-has-flag node-ignore node-imurmurhash
  node-inflight node-inherits node-is-extglob node-is-glob node-isarray node-js-yaml node-json-schema node-json-schema-traverse node-json-stable-stringify node-jsonify node-levn node-lodash node-lru-cache node-memfs node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-ms
  node-object-assign node-once node-optionator node-path-dirname node-prelude-ls node-process-nextick-args node-progress node-punycode node-re2 node-readable-stream node-regenerate node-regenerate-unicode-properties node-regexpp
  node-require-from-string node-resolve-from node-rimraf node-safe-buffer node-semver node-sprintf-js node-string-decoder node-strip-ansi node-strip-json-comments node-supports-color node-text-table node-type-check node-typedarray node-undici
  node-uri-js node-util-deprecate node-v8-compile-cache node-wrappy node-write node-xtend node-yallist nodejs nodejs-doc nvidia-firmware-550-550.107.02 python3-bpfcc python3-netaddr thermald ubuntu-kernel-accessories
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic (6.8.0-48.48) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-48-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j16 KVER=6.8.0-48-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.8.0-48-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-48-generic/x86_64 succeeded for 8812au nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-48-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-48-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-47-generic (6.8.0-47.47) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-47-generic (6.8.0-47.47) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-47-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j16 KVER=6.8.0-47-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.8.0-47-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-47-generic/x86_64 succeeded for 8812au nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-47-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-47-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-47-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.8.0-47-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-47-generic (6.8.0-47.47) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-47-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j16 KVER=6.8.0-47-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.8.0-47-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-47-generic/x86_64 succeeded for 8812au nvidia
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-47-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-47-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-47-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-47-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-6.8.0-47-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-47-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


I ran apt autoremove, but I am getting the same error.
Correct me if I am wrong here, but it seems from the log that the issue arises due to the linux-headers-generic package, which has two versions installed on my system: 6.8.0-48 and 6.8.0-47. This might be the reason for the rtl8812au error:
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.3.4 not found

I looked up on this particular error and found this post, but I am not sure if the answers there would work, since mine is a different version. I also found another post with a similar issue as me, but the accepted answer there doesn't work for me: I tried installing the dkms package using apt-get install dkms, and cleaning and reinstalling the linux-headers-generic package, but all to no avail; I get the same error. apt remove dkms is no different.
Any pointers on how I should proceed would be helpful. Would be happy to provide any other information if needed.
EDIT: Here's the output of dkms status:
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 6.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 6.8.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 6.8.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
evdi/1.14.2+dfsg, 6.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
evdi/1.14.2+dfsg, 6.8.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/550.120, 6.8.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/5.3.4: added

Output of uname -r is 6.8.0-47-generic, and dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc' gives me:
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=======================================================-========================================-============-===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
iF  linux-headers-6.8.0-47-generic                          6.8.0-47.47                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP



In file /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source/dkms.conf comment out the line starting with REMAKE_INITRD .

@nobody okay that helped with the deprecation warnings, but I'm still getting the linux-headers-generic errors.

Please add dkms status and uname -r also dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc' to your question.

Probably due to the module sources not keeping up with the kernel changes. (It looks like your update went through two.) You probably need to see if your build sources have been updated. If not then may I suggest you use the version pointed to by the following answer of the question here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1531937/tp-link-ac600-archer-driver-for-linux-ubuntu-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts/1531940#1531940 The instructions are for RTL8821au and RTL8812au (there was some confusion for this question which one was needed) so choose the one you require (RTL8812au).
