TP Link T2U Plus Not connecting nor showing any networks (24.04)
I run Ubuntu 24.04, I switched from Windows because i got pissed off at a multi billion dollar company that cannot make a proper update. Anyways, I have a TP Link, I tried every driver I could find on GitHub, but nothing worked, I reset the NetworkManager multiple times after every driver install. Still nothing. I found people with the same problem fixed it with one driver which I downloaded and I still have the same issue. The system recognizes the adapter but it doesn't seem to communicate with the router? If anyone could help I would be thankful. Kernel version is 6.8.0.
lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2530 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0012 C-Media Electronics, Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:f22a HP, Inc HP Laser MFP 135w
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0e8d:2004 MediaTek Inc. CRT-LX1
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 258a:0049 BY Tech Gaming Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2357:0120 TP-Link Archer T2U PLUS [RTL8821AU]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

EDIT: The issue was the .conf file for the driver was not configured good.

The answer to the following question contains the driver you are using (RTL8821AU) and I know it works as I have it installed for my device (24.04 6.8.0-48-generic). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1531937/tp-link-ac600-archer-driver-for-linux-ubuntu-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts/1531940#1531940 (Note: there was some confusion as to the driver in this case so the instructions contain two variations. Just choose the one you require.

Thanks for the help, I figured the .conf was bad in the driver, I changed some values and now it's working.

@sseki Please post the preceding comment as an answer to your own question. Then click the gray check beside your answer to mark it as accepted. You might have to wait one more day to accept your own answer.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am very happy that you found the solution to your question.This is a question answer site. Please do not put SOLVED in the question title and the answer inside the question. Click the Answer Your Own Question button below. Explain in your answer what exact changes you made to the .conf file. That will help others.

Thanks for the help, I figured the .conf was bad in the driver, I changed some values and now it's working.
.conf file (I left the comments since I am new to this, they are helpful):
# /etc/modprobe.d/8821au.conf
#
# Purpose: Allow easy access to specific driver options.
#
# Edit the following line to change, add or delete driver options:
#
options 8821au rtw_led_ctrl=1
#
# Note: The above `options` line is a good default for managed mode. Below
# are examples for AP mode. Modify as required after reading the documentation:
#
# Band 1 (2.4 GHz)
#options 8812au rtw_switch_usb_mode=2
#
# Band 2 (5 GHz)
#options 8812au rtw_switch_usb_mode=1 rtw_vht_enable=2 rtw_dfs_region_domain=1 rtw_country_code=US rtw_power_mgnt=0
#
# After editing is complete, save this file (if using nano: Ctrl + x, y, Enter)
# and reboot to activate the changes.
#
# Note: hostapd information is located at the end of this file.
#
# Documentation:
#
# -----
#
# Log options ( rtw_drv_log_level )
#
# 0 = NONE (default)
# 1 = ALWAYS
# 2 = ERROR
# 3 = WARNING
# 4 = INFO
# 5 = DEBUG
# 6 = MAX
#
# Note: You can save a log file that only includes RTW log entries by running
# the following in a terminal:
#
# sudo ./save-log.sh
#
# Note: A log option greater than 1 must be set. The name of the log
# file will be `rtw.log`.
#
# -----
#
# LED options ( rtw_led_ctrl )
#
# 0 = Always off
# 1 = Normal blink (default)
# 2 = Always on
#
# -----
#
# VHT options ( rtw_vht_enable )
#
#  0 = Disable
#  1 = Enable (default)
#  2 = Force auto enable (use only for 5 GHz AP mode)
#
# Notes:
# - A non-default setting can degrade performance greatly in managed mode.
# - Option 2 allows 80 MHz channel width for 5GHz AP mode, such as when
#   you are using hostapd.
#
# -----
#
# Power options ( rtw_power_mgnt )
#
# 0 = Disable power saving
# 1 = Power saving on, minPS (default)
# 2 = Power saving on, maxPS (not recommended for AP mode)
#
# -----
#
# DFS Options ( rtw_dfs_region_domain )
#
# 0 = NONE (default)
# 1 = FCC
# 2 = MKK
# 3 = ETSI
#
# Notes:
# - Activates DFS channels in AP mode.
# - DFS FCC 80 MHz channels for hostapd: 52(58), 100(106), 116(122) and 132(138)
# - For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels
#
# Note: An AP needs to listen on a DFS channel for a period of 60 seconds
# before transmitting on the channel. If any radar pulses are detected,
# the AP cannot use that channel and will have to try a different channel.
#
# -----
#
# Wireless Mode options ( rtw_wireless_mode )
#
# 1  = 2.4GHz 802.11b
# 2  = 2.4GHz 802.11g
# 3  = 2.4GHz 802.11b/g
# 4  = 5GHz 802.11a
# 8  = 2.4Hz 802.11n
# 11 = 2.4GHz 802.11b/g/n
# 16 = 5GHz 802.11n
# 20 = 5GHz 802.11a/n
# 64 = 5GHz 802.11ac
# 84 = 5GHz 802.11a/n/ac
# 95 = 2.4GHz 802.11b/g/n 5GHz 802.11a/n/ac (default)
#
# -----
#
# Country Code options ( rtw_country_code )
#
# Note: Allows the Country Code to be set in cases where it is unable to
# be obtained otherwise.
#
# URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2
#
# Example for the US: rtw_country_code=US
# Example for Panama: rtw_country_code=PA
# Example for Norway: rtw_country_code=NO
# Example for Kuwait: rtw_country_code=KW
# Example for Taiwan: rtw_country_code=TW
#
# -----
#
# To see all driver options that are available:
#
# $ ls /sys/module/8821au/parameters/
#
# -----
#
# To see the values that are in use:
#
# $ grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/8821au/parameters/*
#
# -----
#
# hostapd setup information for rtl8821au
# Note: The best settings can vary but the following may be a good place to start.
#
# /etc/modprobe.d/8821au.conf
# options 8821au rtw_drv_log_level=0 rtw_led_ctrl=0 rtw_vht_enable=2 rtw_power_mgnt=1 rtw_dfs_region_domain=1
#
# Note: The best setting for `rtw_dfs_region_domain=` will depend on your location.
#
# /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
#
# hw ht capab: 0x962
# ht_capab=[HT40+][HT40-][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][RX-STBC1][MAX-AMSDU-7935]
#
# hw vht capab: 0x3c00122
# vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-11454][SHORT-GI-80][RX-STBC-1][HTC-VHT][MAX-A-MPDU-LEN-EXP7]
#
# -----

